# Can I Extract Data from a Site in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I want make a site on which a user enters a URL and the whole page is shown on my site. How to do this in PHP? Without iframes or embedding.

I want to know if there is any function like 'get data' or 'go to url' or something like that.

Comment: so you want to show the entire content of example.com where?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following to get the contents of the page.

```
<?php

$url = "http//www.example.com/example";
$file = file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

And then work with that data to do what you need to. An IFrame is probably a better solution however, as all that data is not being proxied through your website.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

`echo file_get_contents($url);`

probably safer and better to go with cURL though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to get the contents of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing what other's have said, you would have to implement your own script to traverse trough the page and change the url of embedded scripts and css file from this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" herf="style.css" />` to this `<link rel="stylesheet" herf="http://www.url.com/style.css" />`